# JQWidget Tree in Splitter scrolls to top unexpectedly

Tags: jquery, tree, jqwidget

I am relatively new to JQuery.

I have a JQWidgets Splitter, and inside the left pane I put a JQWidgets Tree.  The tree is long enough that I need a scroll to see all of it.  When I expand a node, the left pane re-draws so that, although the node is expanded, the scroll bar is at the top of the pane containing the tree.  I can't see the node I just expanded.  I would like the position of the scrollbar to remian where it is, so that the node I just expanded remains under the cursor.  The issue is pretty easy to reproduce.

```
....
<div id='splitter'>
    <div id='splitter-left'>
        <div id='tree'>
            <ul><li></li>...</ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='splitter-right'>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
...
<script type='text/javascript>
    $(function () {
        $("#splitter").jqxSplitter();
        $("#tree").jqxTree();
    });
</script>
```

I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkipSailors/b2sLk3t8/1/) demonstrating this behavior, that has all the CSS and JScript references.  It has a list of lists long enough to overflow.  How do I make the tree quit bouncing around when I expand nodes?

Note: the tree behaves as I expect if it is not in a splitter.  It seems to be something about the collaboration of the tree and the splitter that causes this.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Tree's height to 100% so the widget will use its ScrollBar for scrolling and the Browser will not auto-scroll on Focus. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6cr22ygy/

```
<div id="splitter">
    <div id="splitter-left" style="overflow: auto">
        <div style='border:none;' id="tree">
            <ul>
                <li>root
                    <ul>
                        <li>a</li>
                        <li>b</li>
                        <li>c</li>
                        <li>d
                            <ul>
                                <li>da</li>
                                <li>db</li>
                                <li>dc</li>
                                <li>dd
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>dda</li>
                                        <li>ddb</li>
                                        <li>ddc</li>
                                        <li>ddd</li>
                                        <li>dde</li>
                                        <li>ddf</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>e</li>
                        <li>f</li>
                        <li>g</li>
                        <li>h</li>
                        <li>i</li>
                        <li>j</li>
                        <li>k</li>
                        <li>l</li>
                        <li>m</li>
                        <li>n</li>
                        <li>o</li>
                        <li>p</li>
                        <li>q</li>
                        <li>r</li>
                        <li>s</li>
                        <li>t</li>
                        <li>u</li>
                        <li>v</li>
                        <li>w</li>
                        <li>x</li>
                        <li>y
                            <ul>
                                <li>ya</li>
                                <li>yb</li>
                                <li>yc</li>
                                <li>yd</li>
                                <li>ye</li>
                                <li>yf</li>
                                <li>yg</li>
                                <li>yh</li>
                                <li>yi</li>
                                <li>yj</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>z
                            <ul>
                                <li>za</li>
                                <li>zb</li>
                                <li>zc</li>
                                <li>zd</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="splitter-right">
         <h3>Steps to Reproduce</h3>

        <ol>
            <li>Run</li>
            <li>expand root</li>
            <li>Scroll to y</li>
            <li>expand y</li>
        </ol>
         <h3>Expect</h3>

        <p>node expanded and visible (position preserved in pane)</p>
         <h3>Observe</h3>

        <p>node expanded, but tree has been repositioned to top of pane</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $("#splitter").jqxSplitter();
    $("#tree").jqxTree({height:"100%"});
});
```

More info about jQWidgets Tree height property: [jQWidgets Tree API](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxtree/jquery-tree-api.htm)